# ComboBox Color Picker with LivePreview, set up itemssource at ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, itemssource

I like to build some ColorPicker app with help of ComboBox and LivePreview. I came a cross with already with first issue. I ComboBox I like to show rectangle with fill of selected color and textblock with name of the color. Colors will be manual choosen over RGB pallete.

My problem is that ComboBox dont show any of Color and no text. I attached code below, if any question please ask. I belive that my problem is in XAML code?

Now ComboBox show me only "ColorPickerWithLivePreview.ButtonIlluminationViewModel+ColorItem" - two lines of that because I have two colors in List.

ViewModel:

```
public class ButtonIlluminationViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public string ButtonName
    {
        get
        {
            return "Button Illumination";
        }
    }

    public ButtonIlluminationViewModel()
    {
        ColorList = new List<ColorItem>()
        {
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "AppleGreen", Color = Color.FromArgb(255,255,255,255)},
            new ColorItem() { ColorName = "AppleGreen", Color = Colors.Red },
        };
    }

    public IList<ColorItem> ColorList
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public class ColorItem
    {
        public string ColorName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Color Color
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<local:LivePreviewComboBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="liveBox" Width="200" SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}" >
            <local:LivePreviewComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20" Fill="{Binding }" Margin="1"/>
                        <TextBlock Height="20" Text="{Binding }" Margin="1"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </local:LivePreviewComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </local:LivePreviewComboBox>
```

LivePreviewComboBox:

```
public class LivePreviewComboBox : ComboBox
{

    #region DependencyProperty LivePreviewItem

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the live preview item.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The live preview item.</value>
    public object LivePreviewItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(LivePreviewItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LivePreviewItemProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dependency property to get or set the live preview item
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LivePreviewItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LivePreviewItem", typeof(object), typeof(LivePreviewComboBox),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

    #endregion

    #region Construction

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="LivePreviewComboBox"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    public LivePreviewComboBox()
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(IsDropDownOpenProperty, typeof(LivePreviewComboBox))
                .AddValueChanged(this, OnDropDownOpenChanged);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overrides

    /// <summary>
    /// See <see cref="ComboBox.OnSelectionChanged" />
    /// </summary>
    protected override DependencyObject GetContainerForItemOverride()
    {
        var container = base.GetContainerForItemOverride();
        var comboBoxItem = container as ComboBoxItem;
        if (comboBoxItem != null)
        {
            DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ComboBoxItem.IsHighlightedProperty, typeof(ComboBoxItem))
                .AddValueChanged(comboBoxItem, OnItemHighlighted);
        }
        return container;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// See <see cref="ComboBox.OnSelectionChanged" />
    /// </summary>
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        LivePreviewItem = SelectedItem;
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Private Helpers

    private void OnItemHighlighted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBoxItem = sender as ComboBoxItem;
        if (comboBoxItem != null && comboBoxItem.IsHighlighted)
        {
            LivePreviewItem = comboBoxItem.DataContext;
        }
    }

    private void OnDropDownOpenChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsDropDownOpen == false)
        {
            LivePreviewItem = SelectedItem;
        }
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to bind the Textblock Text and Rectangle Fill to the actual properties of the ColorItem.

You also need to bind the Fill property to a property of type Brush instead of Color. You can make a Brush from a color like this:

```
new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Blue);
```

Comment: OK, now text is binding but color is not binding. Rechtangle is always white

Comment: Thanks. I already see it when you give me first answer :D Thanks. I change XAML file .. Rechtanglefild to: <Rectangle><Rectangle.Fill><SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Color}"/></Rectangle.Fill>></Rectangle>..... Thanks!!!

Comment: Or Maybe is better to change in C code to user SolidColorBrush, because of LivePreview which now dont works :D